PROFTPD / SWAPPED FILES / downloading a file contains the contents of another file, but the file name is correct
I am facing a problem on my PROFTPD server on which there is a lot of traffic.
installed on CENTOS8 server with docker.
ProFTPD Version 1.3.7a
Take for example two clients:
Client-1 requests the download of the X.jpg image via its application.
Client-2 requests the download of the Y.jpg image from its application at the same time as client-1.
In rare cases, client-2 downloads the image with the correct name (Y.jpg), but when we open the image, it is the X.jpg that is displayed.
here in my capture for example, it's a customer who only sells books, but he ends up with an image of shoes.

when I look at the FTP server, the image is correct, it's not a shoe.
in my proftpd logs, I see that the shoe and the photo of the book are downloaded at the same time.
So, if you have an idea or a lead I'm interested, because this bug is causing me a lot of problems!
Thank you in advance for your help.

The PROFTPD developers gave me a response on github.
Possibly a problem related to this issue. it was fixed from version 1.3.7b.
I'm trying an update this weekend and I'll post the results.
